# What are some generic steps to take when Visual Studio says "the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When working with C#, MS Visual Studio has a tendency when faced with code it doesn't like to give an error message that reads "*the best overloaded method match for* <method signature> *has some invalid arguments*". This message is unfortunately low on detail as to what's actually wrong, and consequently being faced with it can prove frustrating. Searching this site or the web at large for the phrase throws up a great many examples of questions, forum threads etc. where people have asked what is wrong in **their specific situation** where they have encountered this error. I'd like to know what **general steps** one might take to determine the nature of the underlying problem when faced with this error message.

Note that this question *was* prompted by an instance of seeing this error message in Visual Studio, but I'm deliberately not posting my code because I want generic troubleshooting advice (related to this error message), not specific help with whatever error is present in my code at this moment (which is likely to be quite pedestrian).

Answer (score 1):

Check each parameter's type to make sure it's what you expect?
The tooltip displays the signature right there.

If you don't know the parameter type you can just make a `var` variable there set to the same value and then hover over `var` to see what type it is.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, check the `Type` of each argument along with the order in which they are needed to be passed..

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, user do mistakes in parameter DataType. 
For Example :

```
Void Test(Int16 num)
  {
   .....
  }
```

While calling this method you miss the datatype like bellow eg in the sense you will face this issue

```
int a = 0;
Test(a);
```

Make sure the variable declaration or use the var declaration

```
var a=0;
```

Comment: Does `var` do that (identify which kind of integer variable `a` is based on it being passed into a method)? I didn't know it was that clever.